# How to calculate O(log n) processing time on an array of size 625?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o

> Suppose an algorithm that processes an array is O (log n). The
>   algorithm takes at most 12 µs to process an array of size 25. All
>   conditions being equal, approximately, at most how long will the
>   algorithm take to process an array of size 625?

Would I solve this by dividing 625/25 = 25 and then multiplying that by the  12 microseconds it takes per 25 elements ((625/25)*12 = 300 microseconds), or is there more to it? For example, would i need to calculate the max number of comparisons using log2(625) + 1 and use that in the calculation? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: This is not a homework question.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: 625 is 25 squared. Power of two. `log(625)` is therefore `log(25)*2`.The processing time will therefore double.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. It's a severe abuse of the big-oh notation. This notation is for the asymptotic behavior. One cannot derive the number of steps the algorithm takes for a fixed n using only this notation. Of course, if it's a homework, the answer they want is 24 as  log 625 / log 25 = 2 * log 25 / log 25 = 2.

Comment: @JonhKugelman It's not. The definition of the big-oh f(n) = O(n) says that there is such a constant C that for sufficiently large n(that is, n > N0) f(n) <= C * g(n). It says absolutely nothing about n < N0. It can literally take 1 year to run for n = 625 (while running in 12 us for n = 25) and still be `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the algorithm takes O(log *n*) time then it takes *C* log *n* + *f*(*n*)  time to process *n* elements. Here *C* is some constant factor and *f*(*n*) is some function which grows slower than O(log *n*).

The worst case for scaling purposes is when the *f*(*n*) term contributes nothing—i.e., when *f*(*n*) = 0—so let's forget about that term. We'll just consider *C* log *n*.

We know that

> *C* log 25 = 12µs

Therefore

> *C* = 12µs / log 25

Now if we plug in 625, we get:

> *C* log *n* = (12µs / log 25) log 625 = **24µs**

(The presumption in my answer is that *f*(*n*) is always non-negative and is monotonically increasing. That's not a mathematical requirement of Big-O notation, but in practice it's a reasonable restriction.)

Comment: If *O(log N)* didn't dominate it wouldn't be *O(log N)*.

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained.

Comment: @JonhKugelman can this same logic/formula be applied to the other time complexities?

Comment: Unfortunately, the presumption is not sufficient. One can define f(n) = n for n < 625, f(n) = 10^100 for n = 625 and f(n) = 10^100 * log n for n > 625. It's non-negative and monotonically increasing and its O(log n). Yet it doesn't yield the 24 for n = 625 (I understand that it's a very pathological case). A sufficient condition (maybe not the weakest one) would be that f(n) <= C * log n  for all n and the bound is actually achieved for n = 25. I'm sorry for being too picky.

Comment: I'm not sure that pathological f(n) invalidates my answer. It's an issue of units. I think your comment is conflating *number of operations* with *time*. Even with that crazy f(n) I can still make the log *n* term grow faster by cranking up its multiplicative constant.